# Subseting dataframe with mutiple simulateneous conditions in R

Tags: r

This is a representative subset of my data:

```
> df
  Sample  Circle      Value
1     a1     C27 0.04829484
2     a2     C27 0.10577841
3     a1     C18 0.03977222
4     a2     C18 0.10319845
5     a1     C16 0.03977222
6     a2     C16 0.03095953
```

I would like to:

1) calculate the maximum $Value for each circle. There are three circles, so I will get 3 maximum values in total. I used :

`Max_df = df %>% group_by(Circle) %>% do(data.frame(Max_value = max(.$Value)))`

```
> Max_df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Circle [3]
  Circle  Max_value
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 C18        0.10319845 
2 C27        0.10577841 
3 C16        0.03977222
```

So it works but it does not keep the information about which $Sample (a1 or a2) has the maximum value. Would you know how to do it?

2) calculate the second maximum value for each circle. I cannot use `min()` because I have much more samples and circles in my real dataset. What I tried to do is to filter out the rows with the maximum values of df using Max_df. And then calculate the maximum values of this filtered df. So it would be the same code as in 1).

However, I do not succeed in filtering out the rows with the maximum values saved in Max_Df. I tried :

```
filter(df, Circle %in% Max_df$Circle & Value %in% Max_df$Max_Value)
```

The issue is that this code keeps the third row of df because its Value is equal to the maximum value of C16 (row 5). Whereas, the third row is absolutely not the maximum value of the circle C18.

So how do I filter a table according to two simultaneous conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `filter()` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

#given dataset
df <- data.frame(Sample = rep(c("a1", "a2"), 3),
                 Circle = c("C27", "C27", "C18", "C18", "C16", "C16"),
                 Value = c(0.04829484, 0.10577841, 0.03977222,
                           0.10319845, 0.03977222, 0.03095953))

#(1)
Max_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Circle) %>%
  filter(Value == max(Value))

#(2)
Second_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Circle) %>%
  filter(Value != max(Value)) %>%
  filter(Value == max(Value))

#(1+2)
Both_df <- Max_df %>%
  rbind(Second_df)
```

Or this `rank()` solution

```
#Adding ranks to df
Rank_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Circle) %>%
  mutate(Value_rank = rank(-Value, ties.method = "first")) 

#(1)
Max_df2 <- Rank_df %>%
  filter(Value_rank == 1) %>%
  select(-Value_rank)

#(2)
Second_df2 <- Rank_df %>%
  filter(Value_rank == 2) %>%
  select(-Value_rank)

#(1+2) - step (1) and (2) are not required
Both_df2 <- Rank_df %>%
  filter(Value_rank %in% 1:2) %>%
  select(-Value_rank)
```

Comment: Worth noting for OP that you don't need to actually create the `Max_Value` column. #2 could be shortened to `df %>% group_by(Circle) %>% filter(Value != max(Value)) %>% filter(Value == max(Value))`. (Also I think you have typo in the first #2... you need `select(-Max_Value)` at the end, not `Value_rank`).

Comment: @GregorThomas, good point, thanks! I will correct typo and adjust solution.

Comment: @MULLERHéloïse since the solution works for you, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please :)